# Why does my c++ code using ofstream fail to crete the file on /tmp subdirectory?

Tags: c++, c++11, permissions, c++14

The following code fails to create the file on /tmp. This happens even if I execute the binary as sudo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        ofstream of("/tmp/DIR1/DIR2/test_file",std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
        of.close();
        return 0;
}
```

If I remove DIR1/DIR2/ from the file path, a test_file does get created on /tmp.
I am using linux mint.

Whats happening here?

Comment: `ofstream` is not a directory creator.  You need to do that with other functions.

Comment: In C++17 and later, you can use [`std::filesystem::create_directory()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory). But in earlier versions, you will have to use platform APIs instead, like [`mkdir()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir) on Linux.

Comment: Why are you not checking errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ file streams do not create directories, only files.

Before C++17 there is no standard function to create directories and you will have to use a OS specific function or an additional library, such as [`mkdir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) on POSIX systems or [`CreateDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya?redirectedfrom=MSDN) on Windows, or [`boost::filesystem::create_directory`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_directory) and others from the Boost library.

Since C++17 there is a filesystem library in the standard. Specifically you would want to took at e.g. [`std::filesystem::create_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory).